# Can I use my raspberry pi as a server without having it connected to my router?

Tags: web-server, internet, server, web

Basically I want to be able to connect to my raspberry pi from outside my house, it has a java server on it (it should be accessible from anywhere) but I don't want people to go through my router, then to the raspberry pi. Is there anyway I can create a public internet connection point from my pi without a router?

Answer (score 1):

Your router *is* the means by which *inside* and *outside* networks are connected.

The only way to have your Pi contactable by the outside world is to connect it to the Internet through a router. So, if you don't want to use "your" router, you'll need to get another one, and an Internet connection for it.

Regardless of through which router your Pi is connected, there are significant security implications to allowing public access to any computing equipment which will need to be addressed, but that's a question for another place and time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need router to connect your computer (whichever it is, even Pi) to the internet - you can connect directly to the internet provider modem. Of course you would need second modem (and router) for the rest of your computers at home ;-)